# Discord API не прилетает пинг на роль и юзера

Tags: javascript, api, discord

По сути роль и юзер отображается, но пинг не приходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
channel.send({ content: `<@!${interaction.member.user.id}> <@&1143276573290680352> <@&1143276573290680353>`,  embeds: [
new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
.setColor(ee.color)
.setFooter({ text: ee.footertext, iconURL: ee.footericon})
.setTitle(`**Создано новое обращение!**`)
.setDescription(`В текущем канале вы можете: **купить нитро или различные урашения для профиля!**`)
```

вот пример кода, не понимаю, что может быть не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил проблему тем, что включил боту разрешение пинговать роли